# How to deploy reportportal into production environment

Tags: reportportal

Based on [deployment](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/wiki/Production-Ready-set-and-Deployment-Customization#production-set) instruction we need to deploy reportportal to the production environment

in the instruction  mentioned the following:

For production usage we recommend to:

deploy MongoDB database at separate enviroment, and connect App to this server. MongoDB is mandatory part.
choose only required Bug Tracking System integration service. Exclude the rest

our question is:
                how to connect first VM with dockerized reportportal to second one VM with hosted database

Maybe there is any environment variable which is pointing app to database?

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of connection settings that should be applied to services which use database. Here is the list:

```
 - rp.mongo.host=XXX
 - rp.mongo.port=27017
 - rp.mongo.dbName=reportportal
 - rp.mongo.user=XXX
 - rp.mongo.password=XXX
```

MongoDB is used by the following services: UAT (authorization), API, JIRA, RALLY. There is example of [docker-compose YAML](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) which contains all mentioned properties.

Answer (score 0):

How i understand, mongo db container should be removed from docker-compose config, hence we should create second config with DB(mongo) container:

```
image: mongo:3.2
## Uncomment if needed
# ports:
#     - "27017:27017"
volumes:
  - reportportal-data:/data/db
restart: always
## Consider disabling smallfiles for production usage
command: --smallfiles
```

And set db settings to first docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Yes, you are right mongodb should be removed from docker-compose file, then you need to inform other containers where Mongo DataBase is located

Comment: There are actually two options: mongo is still here, in docker or mongo is deployed outside. If it's deployed outside, you don't need container so its definition should be removed from docker-compose.yaml. Just keep in mind that you can use docker-swarm (for example) to group several docker nodes into virtual one (make a cluster) - in that case you have several physical machines which can be configured as one docker node. With such approach, you can deploy mongo as container as well